# Using webdav on Android

Tags: android, jaxb, webdav, slide

I'm trying to make a Webdav Client for Android, and I found different Java APIs: Slide, Jakrabbit and Sardine which seems it's a promising solution.  It runs like a charm in a Java Apps, but I encountered problems importing in Android Apps with Jaxb API.

Does any body know any solutions, or suggestions to fix my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is Sardine, but I'm biased since I wrote it after searching around for a decent webdav solution and found that everything out there was difficult to use.

One metric of value is that Sardine is actively being developed by a small community of talented Java developers now, while the other's are not getting nearly as much attention.

https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine

Try it, the price is right! =)

Comment: Hey Jon, I just came across your client and it's looking good! Is it supporting pausing and resuming upload though?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused of how to use this library for Android. Sardine requires JAXB, but there is no JAXB for Android, as I know. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

Does the question concern **Android**? Yes.

So you should try https://github.com/yeonsh/Sardine-Android

Comment: Thanks Pascal but when  I asked this (on March 2011), Sardine-Android did not exist...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this to use sardine. http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/