# Android webdav Java Sardine

Tags: android, client, webdav, sardine

im trying Sardine to make a webdav client in android, im trying this code:

This works perfect on JAVA aplicacion, but crashes in android :(

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    SardineImpl sardine = new SardineImpl((AbstractHttpClient) client,"testuser","test");
    List<DavResource> resources = sardine.getResources("http://demo.sabredav.org/");
    for (int i = 1; i < resources.size(); i++) {  

          System.out.println(resources.get(i));  
}
```

Replacing `System.out.println` by `Toast` i get this

```
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.setRedirectStrategy
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at com.googlecode.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.init(SardineImpl.java:188)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at com.googlecode.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.<init>(SardineImpl.java:182)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at es.sardine.sardine.onCreate(sardine.java:39)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-24 16:05:34.602: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19362):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should try https://github.com/yeonsh/Sardine-Android

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble trying to use Sardine and including Apache HttpClient which would conflict with the version embedded in Android. So I decided to replace it with OkHttp and I have much less trouble. 
Here is the fork I created: https://github.com/thegrizzlylabs/sardine-android

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this q: [Using webdav on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233466/using-webdav-on-android) ? It essentially says that Sardine needs newer HttpClient version than packages with Android, and provides a lick to patched HttpClient 4.1 linkable into Android apps.

Comment: yes i've seen it, but i cant get it works with that httpclient. :(

Answer (score 0):

For you only iterating through the elements on the server this code worked for me:

```
 try{

            Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("username", "password");

            List<DavResource> resources = sardine.list("webdav/server/directory/");
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
            for (DavResource res : resources)
            {
                //for example
                buffer.append(res.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("VIEWER" , e.getMessage());
        }
```

I used the [Sardine-Android](https://github.com/aflx/Sardine-Android) Project Library in combination with the simpleframework.xml.